#  z-index problem with IE7

Tags: css

I am getting z-index problem.I tried to put position:relative and z-index.But still the issue persist.

Below is my Code:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> firstname</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%">
<div class="yui-skin-sam">
<div id="myAutoComplete">
    <input id="myInput" type="text">
    <div id="myContainer"></div>
</div>
</div>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"> lastname</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%">
<input type="text" name="lastName"/>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">address</td>
<td colspan="2"><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='position:relative;float:left;'>
<tr><td width="25%">
<input type="text" name="address"/>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please give some suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot showing what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

"In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly."

To fix the bug, pls simply apply higher z-index to your target element's parent node. ex:

```
<div style="z-index: 3">
    <div style="z-index:1;">
         something here ....
    </div>
</div>
```

If there are tons of nested div, you can exploit javascript to recursively apply higher z-index to parents of such element. Add the script to your page to fix it:

```
$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
    $('div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});
```

I am not sure what's your z-index targeting to, you can change the $('div') to $('whateveryouwant'), all depend on your needs.

Details:

http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

Comment: I tried so many ways,but no luck.Could you please tell how to chnage above html content to avoid the z-index issue.

Comment: I've updated this post, however, you should provide more intact css/html for us to check the issue.